# Unexpected behaving of cin.clear();

Tags: c++, cin

What I want to do:

I want a code storing names into an array of `char*`

My intention to use cin.getline and cin.clear is to make the input 
error safe.

The rules are: It has to be stored up to 10 names or to interupt after a `.` is entered.

In both cases after that the names have to put on cout 1 Name per line.

What my Loop should do: take up to MAX_NAME_LEN letters and everything what extends the max len should get discarded fon the stdin before the next Loop starts.

```
do
{
    cin.getline(szInputRef, MAX_NAME_LEN);
    sizeLastLen = cin.gcount();
    szpNames[sizeIndex] = new char[sizeLastLen];
    strncpy (szpNames[sizeIndex], szInputRef, sizeLastLen);
    szpNames[sizeIndex][sizeLastLen] = '\0';
    sizeIndex++;
    cin.clear();
}
while ((sizeIndex < 10) &&(szpNames[sizeIndex - 1][0] != '.'));

for (sizeIndex = 0; sizeIndex < 10; sizeIndex++)
{
    if (szpNames[sizeIndex][0] == '.')
    {
        break;
    }

    cout << szpNames[sizeIndex] << endl;
}
```

But what actually happens: the Input that extends the number of MAX_NAME_LEN letters gets taken as next Input without the check. So imagine we say for testcase MAX_NAME_LEN is 3

and have a input of:

```
ig
se
nols
```

teh Output would be:

```
ig
se
nol
s
```

And in the case the input is > (MAX_NAME_LEN * 2)
the app crashes as for the second input the checks seem to not appear.
So after all reading about the documentation to cin.clear()

I cant understand why the input even exist anymore to get saved after the call to cin.clear().
And not even any Clou of the behaving of extending input gets stored without the cin.getline check so the app can Crash.

Could anyone explain what I am understanding wrong or what Logical mistake is in my code?

Comment: `cin.clear()` just clears any error flags, you probably want some variant of `cin.ignore(...)`.  Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: Because it is a homework to get to know what char * are and after that get the difference to std::string. I'm finsihed and feel boring so I wanted to extend the Task by making the Input error safe. But wasn't complete sure How cin.ignore has to be called in a way to discard just everything that is queued in the stdin. After that I stobbert over cin.clear() and thought that would do the Job. But probably I was wrong.

Comment: using cin.ignore makes the Loop infinite.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I debugged it with std::ignore and after Fixing my infinite Loop error, it exactly behaves the same way as `cin.clear();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discarding everything that's in the input stream is not generally a useful thing to do. Someone could feed you a file to stdin, for example, in which case you'd discard everything, or your OS might buffer differently than you expect and you'd end up with unpredictable results. What you really want to do is to ignore the rest of the current input line. The easiest way to do this is to say

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Where `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is the largest number in the `std::streamsize` type and a special case for `std::istream::ignore` where it means infinity. What this means is: Ignore infinitely many characters or to the next `'\n'`, whichever comes first.

However, you can't do this unconditionally because `std::istream::getline` consumes the newline if the buffer is large enough; you'd ignore every other line. You have to execute it only if the line was too long to fit into the buffer. When this happens, `std::istream::getline` sets `failbit`, so we end up with

```
if(std::cin.fail()) {
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

By the way, you should also guard against unrecoverable I/O errors and "errors" such as end-of-file. Currently, if someone presses Ctrl+D (Unix) or Ctrl+Z (Windows) while your program runs, it will do funny things. Of course, that is much easier if you use `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. I just could not get the information abstracted, that get line consumes the line break. Nvm . A little question about the behaving is still left to me: Why the app crashes if the input is at least 1 bigger then 2 times the max input? As i understood you, im not discarding the remaining line so why the second time it is read more then maxnamelen from stdin instead of limiting the amount of reading by getline again?

Comment: That is an unrelated bug. The newly allocated buffer is one byte too short (i.e., you write the null terminator one byte past the end of the buffer).